# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() When spaces are present

Tags: php, json

I am making a website that uses the twitch api that searches through the games and lists the streams that are playing said game. Everything works great, except for when I get an error when searching for games that have a space in them. For example, it will list the minecraft streams, but gets an error when trying to do League of Legends.

```
<?php
 $game = $_GET['game']; 
 $json_file = @file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game{$game}", 0, null, null);
 $json = json_decode($json_file);
 foreach ($json->streams as $stream) {
 echo($stream->channel->name);
 echo "<br>";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `urlencode` to prepare the string to be used in an url:

```
$game = $_GET['game']
$game = urlencode($game);
$json_file = @file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game{$game}", 0, null, null);
```